# Most accurate translation for 'ok' in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In English we say the abbreviation 'ok' for 'oll korrect', what would the abbreviation be in Latin?

Comment: [Wiktionary gives a number of different uses of OK.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/OK#English) Which one(s) are you after? No single Latin word can play all those roles as a noun, an adjective, a verb, and an interjection. In modern English it's not really used as an abbreviation for anything; it has its independent new life.

Comment: I closed the question now for lack of detail. If you edit to specify what you're after, we can reopen. See my previous comment.